# Updating database table that has varying inputs in CRUD interface

Tags: mysql

I'm currently doing a small scale CRUD application that connects to a MySQL database.

For the update function, one of the fields allows users to update multiple phone numbers.
i.e. (**Current Info**) Telephone: Phone1(000-000), Phone2(000-101), Phone3 (000-102)

I was wondering if say a user were to perform updates such as deleting and changing phone numbers
i.e. (**Updated Info**) Telephone: Phone1(000-001), Phone2(000-102)

Would it be better for me to compare the changes and update and delete accordingly, or just delete them and add new entries with the new changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you delete entire record instead of compare because comparison process is hard to handle and may be comparison script will be take bit more time for process.